# No matching sls found for 'php-apps' in env 'base'

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following saltstack top file.

```
  'blog.php.*':
    - php-apps
    - php-apps.blog

  'app.php.*':
    - php-apps
    - php-apps.some-app

  '*phpone*':
    - php-apps
    - php-apps.blog
    - php-apps.some-app
```

When I run high state for the above to environments It works fine. like this

`salt 'blog.php.*' state.highstate` or `salt 'app.php.*' state.highstate`

But when I run the same for the third server it fails.

`salt '*phpone*' state.highstate`

Error:

```
No matching sls found for 'php_apps' in env 'base'
```

I went to the minion server and found that the `init.sls` file in `php-apps` is not being copied over to minion cache location `/var/cache/salt/minion/files/base/php-apps`

I am not able to find any logs of state file having any compilation error which could cause this.

I tried the following but It still does not work.

- Cleared master cache
- Cleared minion cache
- Recreated minion from scratch

What am I missing? Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: You can try this: `salt minion cp.list_master saltenv=base` or ` salt '*' state.show_sls file base` so you see what files you have there.From what you are saying it seems like you use git and it's not getting snyced on the master.Another thing you do is delete the configuration on the salt master,restart it,recreate it.This way you force him to resyn everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First , I will use yaml validator to validate the yaml meta structure. i.e.. install kwalify

```
#install kwalify
sudo apt-get install kwalify
# Now try to check the top file with yaml meta-validation 
kwalify -m top.sls 
# to check many yaml sls file
find . | grep "sls"  | xargs   kwalify -m
```

Don't be surprised when salt doesn't verify the most basic meta structure.

Because saltstack using YAML, it also suffer from tab vs space indentation issues, if you didn't force your editor to convert all TABS to fix spaces.

Comment: It was because of tab. I made special chars visible on my editor(Atom).

Comment: saltstack developer should put this under their "saltstack best practices". ;-)