# I am not able to Launch a VM/instance in proxmox from Salt-master

Tags: salt-stack

I have installed Saltsatck(salt-master) on my virtual machine and also installed Proxmox(Cloud) on another virtual machine.
They both are on same network.
Salt-master and proxmox are running successfully.

```
Whenever I run the below command :-

# salt-cloud -p my-proxmox-config mytest

I get the following output :-
[INFO    ] salt-cloud starting
[INFO    ] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.2.245
[INFO    ] Creating Cloud VM mytest
[ERROR   ] Error creating mytest on PROXMOX

The following exception was thrown when trying to run the initial deployment: 

Error: There was a profile error: Failed to deploy VM

Please look at the below config files :-

1. /etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/proxmox.conf 

   proxmox-config:
     user: root@pam or root@pve
     password: oodles
     url: 192.168.2.245
     driver: proxmox
     verify_ssl: False
     minion:
       master: 192.168.2.228

2. /etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/proxmox.conf

  my-proxmox-config :
    provider: proxmox-config
    image: /root/ISO/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
    technology: kvm / Openvz
    host: cloud
    ip_address: 192.168.2.245
    ssh_username: root
    password: oodles
    cpus: 1
    memory: 512
    swap: 512
    disk: 2
    nameserver: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

Please suggest/advice me what to correct from my configurations file .

Thanks
```

Comment: Can you please provide the following output?

`salt-cloud --list-images proxmox-config`

Comment: Hi , 

When I run  
# salt-cloud --list-images proxmox-config

I am getting below output :-

[INFO    ] salt-cloud starting
[INFO    ] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.2.245
[ERROR   ] Failed to get the output of 'proxmox.avail_images()': 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
proxmox-config:
    ----------

Thanks

Comment: Please validate all your yaml configuration using a yaml meta-schema checker.  It is the first diagnosis you must do before troubleshooting saltstack problem,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778890/no-matching-sls-found-for-php-apps-in-env-base/35802507#35802507

Comment: What's the output of  `salt --version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the above issue i.e. now I am able to launch a VM/instance in proxmox from salt-master by doing the below configurations :-

```
1. /etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/proxmox.conf 

proxmox-config:
  minion:
   master_type: standard
   master: '192.x.x.x'
  user: 'root@pam'
  password: "your password"
  url: '192.168.x.x'
  port: '8006'
  driver: proxmox
  verify_ssl: False

2. /etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/proxmox.conf

my-proxmox-config :
    provider: proxmox-config
    image: local:vztmpl/ubuntu-12.04-standard_12.04-1_i386.tar.gz
    technology: openvz
    host: cloud
    ip_address: 192.168.x.x
    ssh_username: root
    password: "your password"
    cpus: 1
    memory: 512
    swap: 512
    disk: 2
    nameserver: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

In the above file, the image option will only work if you have downloaded the desired operating ISO in templates option available in PROXMOX GUI.
Now , you can easily launch a Instance by using below command :-

# salt-cloud -p my-proxmox-config mytest

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is saying that something is wrong with your profile config. We just need to troubleshoot what's going on with it.

I haven't used the proxmox provider, but according to https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/cloud/proxmox.html it looks like for the `image` option you might have to use `local:/root/ISO/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso`.

Also, have you tried just `technology: openvz`?

Comment: Hi ,
I did changes you suggested with both technology and image option

 Still getting the below errors after running the below command :

# salt-cloud -p my-proxmox-config web1

[INFO    ] salt-cloud starting
[INFO    ] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.2.245
[INFO    ] Creating Cloud VM web1
[INFO    ] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.2.245
[ERROR   ] Error creating web1 on PROXMOX
The following exception was thrown when trying to run the initial deployment: 

'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
Error: There was a profile error: Failed to deploy VM

Thanks